# simpleWebRTC RemoteMedia videos not containing proper screenCapture bool

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, screen-capture, simplewebrtc, live-video

I'm trying to implement some WebRTC video via [SimpleWebRTC React component library](https://simplewebrtc.com/).

Im having issues with sharing a screen from User A, and viewing it from user B.

When sharing, User A's LocalMedia contains a media object with `screenCapture: true`

When joining the room and viewing the remote media, User B's RemoteMedia does not contain any media objects that have `screenCapture: true`, but one of the media items is identical apart from that key / value.

```
<SWRTC.RequestDisplayMedia render={(getDisplayMedia) => {
  return <AppButton onClick={() => { getDisplayMedia() }} warning>
    <ScreenShare style={{fontSize: 20}} />
  </AppButton>
}} />
```

This is the `<RequestDisplayMedia />` [component code](https://docs.simplewebrtc.com/#/Components?id=requestdisplaymedia-component) I am using to share my screen from User A's UI, but I can't seem to find if there is anywhere else I need to define / setup this screenShare to be appropriately captured as such.

[Console logs from Local / remote media perspectives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYOrK.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleWebRTC dev here. This issue should be fixed now in 1.7.1.

We were not previously signaling to peers the fact that that a video was a screen capture.

Thanks for the report!